# How to cut the pic to circle through java graphics 2d? And I expect the result is similar to object-fit: cover in css

Tags: java

I want to cut the pic to circle by using java graphics 2d, but the result is unsatisfying. I would like the final pic come as similar as the  "object-fit: cover" comes out in css.

This is the original pic
[original pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/do3kO.png)

Below are my codes and the final result.

```
    BufferedImage testImage = ImageIO.read(new File("/Users/huangruixiang/Desktop/test.png"));
    BufferedImage formatAvatarImage = new BufferedImage(200, 200, BufferedImage.TYPE_4BYTE_ABGR);
    Graphics2D graphics = formatAvatarImage.createGraphics();
    graphics.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
    Ellipse2D.Double shape = new Ellipse2D.Double(0, 0, 200, 200);
    graphics.setClip(shape);
    graphics.drawImage(testImage, 0, 0, 200, 200, null);
    graphics.dispose();
    ImageIO.write(formatAvatarImage,"png",new File("/Users/huangruixiang/Desktop/circle.png"));
```

[resule](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9W7XF.png)

And the effect I want is similar to this
[Expected effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aBTvS.png)

Comment: Your question is not clear.  We're not all familiar with CSS.  Do you want a 200 x 200 pixel cut of the center of the original image?  The top?  The bottom?

Comment: Sorry. Yes, I want to cut the center of the original image.

Comment: The [drawImage](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Graphics.html#drawImage(java.awt.Image,int,int,int,int,java.awt.image.ImageObserver)) you are using "scales if necessary". So you're cropping a scaled version of your image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go.

[image]

You have to use a different `drawImage` method than the one you used.

Here's the complete runnable code.

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class CenterCutImage {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CenterCutImage cci = new CenterCutImage();
        BufferedImage image = cci.readImage("/do3kO.png");
        BufferedImage croppedImage = cci.createCenterCut(image, new Dimension(200, 200));
        String path = "D:\\Eclipse\\Eclipse-2020-workspace\\com.ggl.testing3\\resources";
        cci.writeImage(croppedImage, path, "circle.png");
    }

    public BufferedImage createCenterCut(BufferedImage inputImage, Dimension d) {
        BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(d.width, d.height, BufferedImage.TYPE_4BYTE_ABGR);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) image.getGraphics();
        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

        int x = (inputImage.getWidth() - d.width) / 2;
        int y = (inputImage.getHeight() - d.height) / 2;
        Ellipse2D.Double shape = new Ellipse2D.Double(0, 0, d.width, d.height);
        g2d.setClip(shape);
        g2d.drawImage(inputImage, 0, 0, d.width, d.height, x, y, x + d.width, y + d.height, null);
        g2d.dispose();

        return image;
    }

    public BufferedImage readImage(String filename) {
        try {
            return ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream(filename));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

    public void writeImage(BufferedImage croppedImage, String path, String filename) {
        try {
            ImageIO.write(croppedImage, "png", new File(path + "/" + filename));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```